# Using contextual filter in view

Tags: views

All,

I have been reading and experimenting, but have not been able to achieve the desired result - please offer some guidance.

My site has two content types: meeting and presenter. At each meeting, there are zero, one, or two presenters. Content type Meeting has a field type of Node reference whose 'number of values' is set to 2. When a Meeting content item is created, it is very simple to link the associated presenter.

The challenge is properly configuring the view. I would like to show each meeting's presenter(s) with the meeting information, whether I am showing just next month's meeting or an archive of past meetings.

I created a view based on Content type Meeting and created a relationship to the linked Presenter (by checking the box Content: Presenter (field_presenter_ref)). Where I am getting stuck, I think, is with the contextual filter. Based on my reading, I should be using Content: NID, but this does not seem to be doing anything for me. Specifically, if I remove date filters, the View shows all presenters from all meetings, not just the one associated with a specific meeting.

Looking forward to learning how to do this correctly - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's not necessary to add the relationship. When you have added the presenters in the Meeting node by use the node reference. You can just add the Presenters field (node reference field) in the Field section of the view without using relationship. Because the node reference is already taking care of the relationship part.

Does this help in any way?
Let me know.

Comment: Zebda, Thanks for taking time to reply. You are correct - if all I wanted to add was the name of the presenter then there is no need to add the relationship. However, I would also like to show other fields associated with content type Presenter, for example, the subject of the presentation. If I simply add this field to the view, without the relationship, it does not get populated (which seems to make sense as the primary query is based on content type Meeting, thus there is no way to pull in field from the related Presenter content type unless the system is informed of the relationship).

Comment: And the presentation field is in the Presenter Content Type?